# How to Get js.map Files to Work With UMD Modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I have the following TS Files:

### MapTest

```
module Test
{
    export function myTest() {
        const zero = 0;
        const two = zero + 2;
        const four = two + two;
        const six = four + two;
        console.log(six);
    }
}
```

### MapModuleTest.ts

```
export module Test
{
    export function myTest() {
        const zero = 0;
        const two = zero + 2;
        const four = two + two;
        const six = four + two;
        console.log(six);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to set break points and debug the TypeScript for `MapTest` in either Chrome or FireFox, everything works as expected.  When I attempt to debug `MapModuelTest.ts`, the TypeScript line appears to be two lines ahead in both Chrome and Firefox than the actual JS.  So if I put a breakpoint on this line `const six = four + two;` it acts as if the JS is actually breaking on line this line `const two = zero + 2;` (i.e. `zero` is defined to be `0`, but `two` is `undefined`)

Is this a known bug?  Does UMD generation need something different in order to work correctly for .map files?

The debugger window is even more interesting in that the local does not match the console.
[image]

Here are the related JS and Map files

#### MapTest.js

```
var Test;
(function (Test) {
    function myTest() {
        var zero = 0;
        var two = zero + 2;
        var four = two + two;
        var six = four + two;
        console.log(six);
    }
    Test.myTest = myTest;
})(Test || (Test = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=MapTest.js.map
```

#### MapTest.js.map

```
{"version":3,"file":"MapTest.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["MapTest.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA,IAAO,IAAI,CASV;AATD,WAAO,IAAI;IAEV;QACC,IAAM,IAAI,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;QACf,IAAM,GAAG,GAAG,IAAI,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;QACrB,IAAM,IAAI,GAAG,GAAG,GAAG,GAAG,CAAC;QACvB,IAAM,GAAG,GAAG,IAAI,GAAG,GAAG,CAAC;QACvB,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;IAClB,CAAC;IANe,WAAM,SAMrB,CAAA;AACF,CAAC,EATM,IAAI,KAAJ,IAAI,QASV"}
```

#### MapModuleTest.js

```
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var Test;
    (function (Test) {
        function myTest() {
            var zero = 0;
            var two = zero + 2;
            var four = two + two;
            var six = four + two;
            console.log(six);
        }
        Test.myTest = myTest;
    })(Test = exports.Test || (exports.Test = {}));
});
//# sourceMappingURL=MapModuleTest.js.map
```

#### MapModuleTest.js.map

```
{"version":3,"file":"MapModuleTest.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["MapModuleTest.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;;;;;;IAAA,IAAc,IAAI,CASjB;IATD,WAAc,IAAI;QAEjB;YACC,IAAM,IAAI,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;YACf,IAAM,GAAG,GAAG,IAAI,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;YACrB,IAAM,IAAI,GAAG,GAAG,GAAG,GAAG,CAAC;YACvB,IAAM,GAAG,GAAG,IAAI,GAAG,GAAG,CAAC;YACvB,OAAO,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,GAAG,CAAC,CAAC;QAClB,CAAC;QANe,WAAM,SAMrB,CAAA;IACF,CAAC,EATa,IAAI,GAAJ,YAAI,KAAJ,YAAI,QASjB"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've logged this as a bug.  Hopefully this can get fixed:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25079

### Update

This appears to have been an issue with the es6-promise library I was using to pollyfill promises. Once I switched to something something >= es6 for my compiling, the mapping worked correctly.